# Compare only one value from array of objects Javascript(No Sorting)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there an optimal way to compare a property value from two array of objects using lodash/underscorejs?

I have an array like this.

```
var a = [{'text':1}, {'text':2, 'misc':22}, {'text':3}];
var b = [{'text':1}, {'text':2}, {'text':3}];
```

comparing a and b should return true based on the property 'text'.

Have tried using `_.isEqual` and `_.isMatch` with not much help.

Here is the **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mhqpe06h/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) `_.pluck( list, key)` to get the values of `key` in a list of objects in `list`, so get the values of `text` and compare

```
_.isEqual(_.pluck(a, "text"),_.pluck(b, "text"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mhqpe06h/1/

Comment: Thank you, it was quick and easy. Accepting this as answer, as I was looking for underscorejs based.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy without any library, although libraries provide alternative implementations for [**`Array#every`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var same = a.length === b.length && a.every(function(value, index) {
    return value.text === b[index].text;
});
```

Comment: This assumes that both arrays are sorted

Comment: Of course, I assume the array is used as a list, so the order is important. For me `[a, b]` is certainly different from `[b, a]`. If that's not what the OP wants, they should clarify their question.